# How to sum some file length in a directory by Julia in awk like method?

Tags: julia

I often process text by unix shell utilities, is there similar function in Julia? Does similar process in julia will write less code in awk?

e.g. to show sum of file lengths in a directory by linux shell

```
ls -l /etc/*.conf  | awk '{s += $5} END{print s}'
```

What I do in julia is

```
using Glob
n=0
for file in glob("*conf","/etc")
  global n += stat(file).size
end
println(n)
```

Is there functions in Julia work like shell's awk, read from output of `ls -l`, and sum the 5-th column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSV.jl` can parse CLI output so you can work with data similarly to `awk`. Just make sure that the output is uniform: prefer tools like `find` to `ls`.

```
using CSV
# awk like behavior
read2(x; args...) = CSV.read(x; header=false, delim=' ', ignorerepeated=true, args...)
reduce(+, read2(`find /etc -maxdepth 1 -name "*conf" -printf "%s\n"`)[:,1])
```

When possible, working completely in Julia is so much nicer :)

```
using Glob
mapreduce(file -> stat(file).size, +, glob("*conf","/etc"))
```

Comment: the mapreduce method works, but the `ls -l /etc/*conf` is not workable is not workable, because in Julia, wildcard is not usable

Comment: I'm trying to modify as `read(\`bash -c "ls -l /etc/*conf"\`, header=false, delim=' ', ignorerepeated=true)`, but failed on missing rows

Comment: If possible, could you just keep the shell command like `ls -l /etc/*.conf` instead of use `find`? I just find `CSV.read` 0.5.22 is not easy to config for read `ls`'s result

Comment: I just found the CSV.read has the ability to detect column data type, for the `Nov 12 18:22` and `Oct 13  2018`, it will fail on auto detection.  May be require to treat all column as String will behavior like `awk` more.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in general, if you want to read an external program's text output as text, use `` read(`command in backticks`, String) ``. So to capture ls output to `text` you would use

```
text = read(`ls -l`, String)
```

which is how CSV.jl is reading the ls output in another answer to your question.

So then

```
lines = strip.(split(text, "\n"))
# skip short lines < length 20, they are not listing lines
answer = sum([parse(Int, split(line, r"\s+")[5]) for line in lines if length(line) > 20])
```